# const function doesn't return char*

Tags: function, constants

Can anyone explain me why if I make the function get_fName a const function, it returns _fName only with the casting (char*)? Without casting, it not compiles.
On the other hand, if I remove the const, it returns _fName also without casting?

```
 class Student
{
    int _id;
    char _fName [20];
        char* get_fName() const;
}
// implementation
  char* Student::get_fName () const
{
    return (char*)_fName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is the expected behaviour. When you declare a function `const`, you're effectively saying "this function will not modify the class' member variables". Thus, all the member variables to such a function appear as `const`. GCC emphasizes this in the error message :

```
x.cpp: In member function ‘char* Student::get_fName() const’:
x.cpp:11:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
     return _fName;
            ^
```

This is because, to a `const` function, `_fName` appears to be a `const char[20]`. Conversion to a `char[20]`, which would be modifiable, is not allowed unless you use a C-style cast or `const_cast`. When you don't declare the function `const`, `_fName` appears to be a `char[20]`, which is implicitly convertible to `char*`, and the function works without casting.

However, this should not be done : if you need a function to modify the object's internals, simply don't declare it `const`, as it violates the contract you state that the function is making.

On another note, consider using `std::string` for storing strings in your program.

Comment: but I'm not modifying it, there is no any change, I only return the string.

Comment: By returning `char*`, you're allowing the caller of `get_fName()` to modify the string. There is no `const` there anymore.

Comment: I want to comment but I don't know how to print a new line here, even after reading help

Comment: if you will try the same with int and int* it will compile

Comment: @leonid1990 : That's very different. If you return an `int`, you're returning it by value, so the value of the member variable stays the same. If you write a getter returning `int*`, you're also returning it by value : the member variable will not be modified, and declaring a getter `const` does not restrict modifications to what an `int*` might point to (as an `int*` member variable in a `const` member function is really a `int *const`, not `const int*`, as you might expect).

Comment: I mean that you define, for example, _id as int*, get_id() will return also int*, and inside the function you will write: "return _id".